# how to update table in php using form values

Tags: php

I am facing a problem i have to update member table where a user can change his password now how many input fields i should put for user 1 or 2
i) 1 for password only(how i will tell database about user id)
ii) if i put 2 one for user id and second for password (i am using it but not working)
my code is :::

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password =$_POST['pw'] WHERE user_id=$_POST['usrid']") or die(mysql_error());
```

question no 2.
in the same way can i put a update button near submit button so that on later stage whole or partially data of any field can be updated if meet a mistake during normal data entry

Comment: enclose data in single quote `password ='$_POST["pw"]'` And you are vulnerable to sql injection. Use Prepare Statements.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your password field to be a String so you need to quote this value in your statement

`"UPDATE members SET password = '" . $_POST['pw'] . "' WHERE user_id=$_POST['usrid']"`

nevertheless, this is super-bad practice, at least you should escape the post-values

i recommend you to have a look into http://php.net/pdo

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password ='".$_POST['pw']."' WHERE user_id= '".$_POST['usrid']."'") or die(mysql_error());
```